# Could not find nokogiri-1.11.4-x86_64-linux in any of the sources - Macbook M1 running Docker

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nokogiri

I'm running a Rails app and getting this error whilst running in Docker.

There are no results on Google for what the cause might be.

The gem doesn't appear in my Gemfile so it must be a dependency of Rails or another gem.

The previous error I was getting was:-

```
Could not find 'nokogiri' (>= 1.5.9) among 144 total gem(s) (Gem::MissingSpecError)
```

To resolve this, I added `gem install nokogiri` to my Dockerfile, which now gives me the title error.  Any ideas?

Comment: try `gem install nokogiri --platform=ruby`, reference: https://nokogiri.org/tutorials/installing_nokogiri.html

Comment: Are you using a non-standard source? (Anything other than rubygems.org?) The message "144 total gem(s)" is a bit surprising to me!

Comment: Also, RE your comment: *"it must be a dependency of Rails or another gem"* -- If you open the `Gemfile.lock`, it should be relatively easy to track down exactly where this dependency originates from!

Comment: @TomLord - thanks, but as far as I'm aware/can see, the Gemfile.lock doesn't say which gem in my Gemfile requested it as a dependency.  

It looks like it was caused by the rails gem though, when I checked the git blame - for some reason we moved it from 6.1.3 to 6.1.0 and that requested the `nokogiri-1.11.4-x86_64-linux` version of nokogiri.  Rails 6.1.3 requests only `nokogiri-1.11.4` which runs fine.

Comment: @s89_ `nokogiri-1.11.4-x86_64-linux` and `nokogiri-1.11.4` are not "different versions". Both are version `1.11.4`, but built for **different platforms**. See the link that was already shared in the top comment.

Comment: Did you try running `gem install nokogiri --platform=ruby`? Did it it give an error? If so, what was the error? What is the output of `gem source`?

Answer (score 2):

When you add `gem install nokogiri` in your Dockerfile, it will install linux compatible nokogiri (1.13.3-x86_64-linux) and will add that to your Gemfile.lock.

When you run rails on your mac, it will need mac compatible nokogiri (1.13.3-x86_64-darwin)

Here is how I fixed this:

- I first ran bundle install from my Mac, that added `1.13.3-x86_64-darwin` in my Gemfile.lock.
- Before running docker-compose up, I added linux platform to my Gemfile.lock by running:
  `bundle lock --add-platform x86_64-linux`

This is what my Gemfile.lock has now:

```
...
    nokogiri (1.13.3-x86_64-darwin)
      racc (~> 1.4)
    nokogiri (1.13.3-x86_64-linux)
      racc (~> 1.4)
...

PLATFORMS
  x86_64-darwin-21
  x86_64-linux
```